# How to solve webpack build errors with Angular5 where I see ...node_modules/xxxx is not part of the compilation output

Tags: webpack, angular5

I have recently upgraded to the most current angular-stater which works fine by itself.  However in my project I am seeing a number of errors like:

```
Module build failed: Error: /home/joel/.../Tracker3/node_modules/angular2-color-picker/lib/index.ts is not part of the compilation output.
```

I have tried directly including this source file in my tsconfig.json or tsconfig.webpack.json but these changes have had no effect.  Clearly I don't yet understand how to properly handle the changes due to addition of ngc-webpack withe angular5.

The 'npm run build' gives:  (which shows the host of build errors)

```
...
7377ms building modules
37ms sealing
4ms optimizing
0ms basic module optimization
41ms module optimization
0ms advanced module optimization
12ms basic chunk optimization
0ms chunk optimization
0ms advanced chunk optimization
4ms module and chunk tree optimization
0ms chunk modules optimization
0ms advanced chunk modules optimization
15ms module reviving
8ms module order optimization
18ms module id optimization
6ms chunk reviving
0ms chunk order optimization
28ms chunk id optimization
61ms hashing
0ms module assets processing
5122ms chunk assets processing
6ms additional chunk assets processing
0ms recording
0ms additional asset processing
0ms chunk asset optimization
235ms asset optimization
133ms emitting
Hash: a180140e440f968bc44e
Version: webpack 3.9.1
Time: 16820ms
                                          Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
        assets/icon/tracker/ms-icon-150x150.png    22.5 kB          [emitted]
           d34bc3300c4ca1084d6416f466e1b7df.gif   75 bytes          [emitted]
                                 main.bundle.js    34.2 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
                            polyfills.bundle.js     595 kB       1  [emitted]  [big]  polyfills
                               inline.bundle.js     5.8 kB       2  [emitted]         inline
                               assets/data.json   30 bytes          [emitted]
 .
 .
 .
         assets/skins/lightgray/content.min.css    3.33 kB          [emitted]
assets/skins/lightgray/fonts/tinymce-small.woff    9.38 kB          [emitted]
                                     humans.txt  251 bytes          [emitted]
                                     robots.txt   31 bytes          [emitted]
                                     index.html    3.03 kB          [emitted]
[./$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive] ./$$_lazy_route_resource lazy 160 bytes {0} [built]
       [] -> factory:62ms building:1ms = 63ms
[./credentials.ts] ./credentials.ts 1.52 kB {0} [built]
       [] -> factory:32ms building:1ms = 33ms
[./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} {1} [built]
       [] -> factory:0ms building:0ms = 0ms
[./src/app/app.component.ts] ./src/app/app.component.ts 1.72 kB {0} [built]
       [] -> factory:29ms building:1ms dependencies:767ms = 797ms
[./src/app/app.module.ts] ./src/app/app.module.ts 14.8 kB {0} [built]
       [] -> factory:230ms building:16ms dependencies:812ms = 1058ms
[./src/app/app.routes.ts] ./src/app/app.routes.ts 542 bytes {0} [built]
       [] -> factory:27ms building:1ms dependencies:172ms = 200ms
[./src/app/environment.ts] ./src/app/environment.ts 1.28 kB {0} [built]
       [] -> factory:23ms building:1ms dependencies:787ms = 811ms
[./src/app/index.ts] ./src/app/index.ts 37 bytes {0} [built]
       [] -> factory:205ms building:1ms = 206ms
[./src/app/tracker/index.ts] ./src/app/tracker/index.ts 234 bytes {0} [built]
       [] -> factory:200ms building:0ms = 200ms
[./src/app/tracker/shared/notification/notification.component.ts] ./src/app/tracker/shared/notification/notification.component.ts 3.02 kB {0} [built]
       [] -> factory:38ms building:3ms dependencies:758ms = 799ms
[./src/app/tracker/shared/specialNotification/specialNotification.component.ts] ./src/app/tracker/shared/specialNotification/specialNotification.component.ts 3.45 kB {0} [built]
       [] -> factory:43ms building:5ms dependencies:751ms = 799ms
[./src/environments/environment.ts] ./src/environments/environment.ts 830 bytes {0} [built]
       [] -> factory:195ms building:2ms = 197ms
[./src/main.browser.ts] ./src/main.browser.ts 966 bytes {0} [built]
        factory:3701ms building:9ms = 3710ms
[./src/polyfills.browser.ts] ./src/polyfills.browser.ts 2.65 kB {1} [built]
        factory:3701ms building:6ms = 3707ms
[./src/service/index.ts] ./src/service/index.ts 323 bytes {0} [built]
       [] -> factory:198ms building:1ms dependencies:4781ms = 4980ms
    + 1709 hidden modules

WARNING in ./node_modules/app-root-path/browser-shim.js
10:8-46 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/app-root-path/browser-shim.js
 @ ./node_modules/codelyzer/angular/config.js
 @ ./node_modules/codelyzer/util/logger.js
 @ ./src/app/tracker/east/body/taskDetailsBody.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/tracker/east/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/tracker/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/angular2-color-picker/lib/index.ts
Module build failed: Error: /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/angular2-color-picker/lib/index.ts is not part of the compilation output. Please check the other error messages for details.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:648:23)
    at plugin.done.then (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:467:39)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
 @ ./node_modules/angular2-color-picker/index.js 5:9-31
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/angular2-logger/app/core/level.ts
Module build failed: Error: /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/angular2-logger/app/core/level.ts is not part of the compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:643:23)
    at plugin.done.then (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:467:39)
    at <anonymous>
 @ ./node_modules/angular2-logger/core.js 6:9-36
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/angular2-logger/app/core/logger.ts
Module build failed: Error: /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/angular2-logger/app/core/logger.ts is not part of the compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:643:23)
    at plugin.done.then (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:467:39)
    at <anonymous>
 @ ./node_modules/angular2-logger/core.js 7:9-37
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/angular2-logger/app/core/providers.ts
Module build failed: Error: /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/angular2-logger/app/core/providers.ts is not part of the compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:643:23)
    at plugin.done.then (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:467:39)
    at <anonymous>
 @ ./node_modules/angular2-logger/core.js 8:9-40
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/ng-socket-io/socket-io.module.ts
Module build failed: Error: /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/ng-socket-io/socket-io.module.ts is not part of the compilation output. Please check the other error messages for details.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:648:23)
    at plugin.done.then (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:467:39)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
 @ ./node_modules/ng-socket-io/index.js 3:25-54
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/ng-socket-io/socket-io.service.ts
Module build failed: Error: /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/ng-socket-io/socket-io.service.ts is not part of the compilation output. Please check the other error messages for details.
    at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:648:23)
    at plugin.done.then (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:467:39)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
 @ ./node_modules/ng-socket-io/index.js 5:26-56
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/font-awesome-webpack/node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/less-loader!./node_modules/font-awesome-webpack/font-awesome-styles.loader.js!./node_modules/font-awesome-webpack/font-awesome.config.js
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'less'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/less-loader/index.js:8:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at loadLoader (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:13:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:173:18
    at loadLoader (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:36:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at runLoaders (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:362:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:182:3)
    at NormalModule.build (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:275:15)
    at Compilation.buildModule (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:151:10)
    at factoryCallback (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:344:12)
    at factory (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:241:5)
    at applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:94:13)
    at /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:268:11
    at NormalModuleFactory.params.normalModuleFactory.plugin (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/webpack/lib/CompatibilityPlugin.js:52:5)
    at NormalModuleFactory.applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:272:13)
    at resolver (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:69:10)
    at process.nextTick (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:194:7)
 @ ./node_modules/font-awesome-webpack/node_modules/style-loader!./node_modules/font-awesome-webpack/node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/less-loader!./node_modules/font-awesome-webpack/font-awesome-styles.loader.js!./node_modules/font-awesome-webpack/font-awesome.config.js 4:14-142
 @ ./node_modules/font-awesome-webpack/index.js
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/app/tracker/west/listHeader/listHeader.component.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../../../node_modules/ng2-dnd/style.css' in '/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/src/app/tracker/west/listHeader'
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/app/tracker/west/listHeader/listHeader.component.scss 3:10-116
 @ ./src/app/tracker/west/listHeader/listHeader.component.scss
 @ ./src/app/tracker/west/listHeader/listHeader.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/tracker/west/listHeader/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/tracker/west/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/tracker/index.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.browser.ts
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html 2.29 kB {0} [built]
            factory:3684ms building:17ms = 3701ms
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
           [] -> factory:10ms building:6ms = 16ms
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
           [] -> factory:11ms building:5ms = 16ms
        + 1 hidden module
```

It seems that these errors are coming from:

```
node_modules/angular2-color-picker/lib/index.ts
node_modules/angular2-logger/app/core/level.ts
node_modules/angular2-logger/app/core/logger.ts
node_modules/angular2-logger/app/core/providers.ts
node_modules/ng-socket-io/socket-io.module.ts
node_modules/ng-socket-io/socket-io.service.ts
```

somehow not being included, but this cannot be correct, since when I include them directly -- there is no improvement.  So what am I doing wrong?  How to properly setup the build for these few node packages???  And why do all the other packages work fine??  Or how can I learn how to fix this?

I have included what I believe are the relevant config files here:
First: webpack.dev.ts:

```
  /**
   * @author: @AngularClass
   */

  const helpers = require('./helpers');
  const buildUtils = require('./build-utils');
  const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge'); // used to merge webpack configs
  const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js'); // the settings that are common to prod and dev
  const fs = require('fs');

  /**
   * Webpack Plugins
   */
  const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');
  const NamedModulesPlugin = require('webpack/lib/NamedModulesPlugin');
  const EvalSourceMapDevToolPlugin = require('webpack/lib/EvalSourceMapDevToolPlugin');


  /**
   * Webpack configuration
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cli
   */
  module.exports = function (options) {
    const ENV = process.env.ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
    const HOST = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

    const METADATA = Object.assign({}, buildUtils.DEFAULT_METADATA, {
      host: HOST,
      port: PORT,
      ENV: ENV,
      HMR: helpers.hasProcessFlag('hot'),
      PUBLIC: process.env.PUBLIC_DEV || HOST + ':' + PORT
    });

    return webpackMerge(commonConfig({ env: ENV, metadata: METADATA  }), {
      /**
       * Options affecting the output of the compilation.
       *
       * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output
       */
      output: {

        /**
         * The output directory as absolute path (required).
         *
         * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-path
         */
        path: helpers.root('dist'),

        /**
         * Specifies the name of each output file on disk.
         * IMPORTANT: You must not specify an absolute path here!
         *
         * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-filename
         */
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',

        /**
         * The filename of the SourceMaps for the JavaScript files.
         * They are inside the output.path directory.
         *
         * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-sourcemapfilename
         */
        sourceMapFilename: '[file].map',

        /** The filename of non-entry chunks as relative path
         * inside the output.path directory.
         *
         * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-chunkfilename
         */
        chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',

        library: 'ac_[name]',
        libraryTarget: 'var',
      },

      module: {

        rules: [

          /**
           * Css loader support for *.css files (styles directory only)
           * Loads external css styles into the DOM, supports HMR
           *
           */
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            include: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
          },

          /**
           * Sass loader support for *.scss files (styles directory only)
           * Loads external sass styles into the DOM, supports HMR
           *
           */
          {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            include: [helpers.root('src', 'styles')]
          },

        ]

      },

      plugins: [
        new EvalSourceMapDevToolPlugin({
          moduleFilenameTemplate: '[resource-path]',
          sourceRoot: 'webpack:///'
        }),

        /**
         * Plugin: NamedModulesPlugin (experimental)
         * Description: Uses file names as module name.
         *
         * See: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/commit/a04ffb928365b19feb75087c63f13cadfc08e1eb
         */
        new NamedModulesPlugin(),

        /**
         * Plugin LoaderOptionsPlugin (experimental)
         *
         * See: https://gist.github.com/sokra/27b24881210b56bbaff7
         */
        new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
          debug: true,
          options: { }
        }),

        // TODO: HMR
      ],

      /**
       * Webpack Development Server configuration
       * Description: The webpack-dev-server is a little node.js Express server.
       * The server emits information about the compilation state to the client,
       * which reacts to those events.
       *
       * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html
       */
      devServer: {
        port: METADATA.port,
        host: METADATA.host,
        hot: METADATA.HMR,
        public: METADATA.PUBLIC,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        https: {
          key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/certwork/newDragon.key'),
          cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/certwork/STAR_dynazu_com.crt'),
          ca: fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/certwork/ssl-bundle.crt')
        },
        watchOptions: {
          // if you're using Docker you may need this
          // aggregateTimeout: 300,
          // poll: 1000,
          ignored: /node_modules/
        },
        /**
        * Here you can access the Express app object and add your own custom middleware to it.
        *
        * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html
        */
        setup: function(app) {
          // For example, to define custom handlers for some paths:
          // app.get('/some/path', function(req, res) {
          //   res.json({ custom: 'response' });
          // });
        }
      },

      /**
       * Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff
       * Description: Node configuration
       *
       * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node
       */
      node: {
        global: true,
        crypto: 'empty',
        process: true,
        module: false,
        clearImmediate: false,
        setImmediate: false
      }

    });
  }
```

The plot thickens: In an attempt to dig further, I did a 'npm run build:prod' which fails differently:

```
         57% building modules 396/442 modules 46 active ...odules/rxjs/operators/windowToggle.jsModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../../../../node_modules/ng2-dnd/style.css' in '/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/src/app/tracker/west/listHeader'
        at factoryCallback (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:276:40)
        at factory (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:235:20)
        at resolver (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:60:20)
        at asyncLib.parallel (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:127:20)
        at /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3874:9
        at /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16
        at iteratorCallback (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1048:13)
        at /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:958:16
        at /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3871:13
        at resolvers.normal.resolve (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:119:22)
        at onError (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:65:10)
        at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
        at runAfter (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
        at innerCallback (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
        at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
        at next (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
        at /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:40:4
        at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
        at runAfter (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:158:4)
        at innerCallback (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:146:3)
        at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
        at next (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
        at innerCallback (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:144:11)
        at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
        at next (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:249:35)
        at resolver.doResolve.createInnerCallback (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:44:6)
        at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
        at afterInnerCallback (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:168:10)
        at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
        at next (/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:252:11)
    resolve '../../../../../node_modules/ng2-dnd/style.css' in '/home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/src/app/tracker/west/listHeader'
      using description file: /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/package.json (relative path: ./src/app/tracker/west/listHeader)
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      after using description file: /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/package.json (relative path: ./src/app/tracker/west/listHeader)
        using description file: /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/ng2-dnd/package.json (relative path: ./style.css)
          no extension
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/ng2-dnd/style.css doesn't exist
          .ts
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/ng2-dnd/style.css.ts doesn't exist
          .js
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/ng2-dnd/style.css.js doesn't exist
          .json
            Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
            /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/ng2-dnd/style.css.json doesn't exist
          as directory
            /home/joel/workspace/Tracker3/node_modules/ng2-dnd/style.css doesn't exist
```

So perhaps these two issues are related? If you have any insight, thanks!

Comment: I added the ng-socket-io package to the angular-starter project along with a socket.service.ts file to ensure that it is being used in the project.  And when I do 'npm run build' that is the normal way to build for development, I see the same errors.  I have submitted an issue in the angular-starter project and I am hopeful that someone with more knowledge will respond.  If I learn enough, perhaps I will be able answer my own question.  Perhaps it is an issue with Angular 5, but it is not clear yet.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the issues were connected to packages that need to be updated for the changes for webpack builds for angular 5.

Also, I had one @include in a scss file where the path needed to be changed due to a change in the ng2-dnd package.

For ng-socket-io, I stopped using this package and grabbed some of the code and inserted it directly into one of my classes.

At this point, I was down to a single error from the angular2-color-picker package that has not been maintained in over a year.  So I switched to the ngx-color-picker package and all now builds!

Thanks to all who looked at this issue and hopefully this answer will help someone else.